# Ionic platform add and ionic build module.js:340

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I created an app using 'ionic start app_name blank'. But i'm getting an error

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\s'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
Hook failed with error code 8: C:\Users\sabari\Desktop\make\vengayam\hooks\after
_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js
```

I'm facing the same error while building the project too.

Someone please help me out. 
thanks in advance. !!!

Comment: Is both cordova and ionic installed globally? Like so...
npm install -g cordova

Comment: yes ,both are installed globally . And only I'm facing this problem. I'm using Windows 8 . My friends with windows 7 seem to get it work good. And I tried all possible corrections I can, And I've added all the resources needed to my path variable. My final option is going to be changing the os to windows 7

Comment: I have built one of the ionic apps on my windows 8 computer within the last month. I think I built the "tabs" one...  
'ionic start myApp tabs  '
I would try it again right now, but my laptop with windows 8 is at home. If you cannot solve this issue by tonight (central standard time), I'll try it again.

Comment: @Onosa Thanks for the help . I solved the problem. I reinstalled nodejs(64 bit) and added its path to my path variable. And the error is gone. Hope this might help others who face the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled nodejs(64 bit) and added its path to my path variable. And the error is gone. Hope this might help others who face the same problem. Still if anyone face the same problem, the problem is definitely not with the operating system. Again make sure to add all necessary things to your path variable in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Specially for **Windows** users the Ionic Team has developed the **Ionic Box**. Take a look here: http://ionicframework.com/blog/ionic-vagrant-android/

> **Ionic Box**, an all-in-one project for setting up hybrid development
>   environments more quickly and easily.